# AJAX + WMPL plugin + WOOCOMMERCE plugin. Can not translate the text in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm using WPML plugin and it works great in my theme except in an ajax.
This is my code:

```
ob_start();
wc_add_notice( __( 'Sorry, the total meals exceeds the limit.', 'woocommerce' ), "error" );
wc_get_template( 'content-subcription-plan.php' );

$woocommerce_order_review = ob_get_clean();
$data = array('fragments' => $woocommerce_order_review);

wp_send_json( $data );
die();
```

I mean the below code does'nt working.

```
__( 'Sorry, the total meals exceeds the limit.', 'woocommerce' )
```

Note: I try above code without ajax and it works great.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think that you will need to use `wp_localize_script()` function with ajax to make it available to WPML for translation. Please have a look to [**Wordpress Function_Reference**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and  [**5 tips for using ajax in wordpress**](http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/). An other trick with wpml in [**Here**](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpml-51?replies=13) at the end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925655/916000